# Import WAR to Another Project In Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, import, project, war

I have create a web service application in netbeans and another web service client in netbeans which the web service client required to access some file from web service project.

I have tried to add project from web service to web service client but fail to add WAR.

How to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: I think i need to separate it out to a normal Java application (JAR) and reference by another project but it used JPA. I wonder this is possible.  I guess i save as long as i did not uses any features from WAS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import WAR into another project by creating EAR project and composes all the necessary JAR.

Comment: How to create EAR?