# Giving the war from local system rather than from Maven repo

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to manipulate an open source project, where I have made my changes and created the WAR file. The WAR file that I have created is an "dependency" for an another module.

The code for that "dependent" module uses `org.eclipse.aether.artifact.DefaultArtifact` like this:

```
public static DefaultArtifact getReportArtifact(String version) {
        return new DefaultArtifact(ALLURE_GROUP_ID, ALLURE_REPORT_FACE_ARTIFACT_ID,"WAR", version);
    }
```

to get the WAR and builds it jar.

I need to pass the my local WAR file, instead of it getting from the Maven repo. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281913/import-war-to-another-project-in-netbeans

Comment: no your wrong. Its not what I'm looking

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693322/eclipse-web-project-dependencies

Comment: @pd30: please understand and post. Your wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Cant you create a jar of your updated project and add it directly in your dependent proj rather than passing it a WAR? If yes, then let me know I can help you add your JAR without fetching it from the repo.

Comment: You are stating which kind of solution you want without stating why it is needed. There are many different ways to get a dependency files locally: local repositories, dependency plugins, system dependencies etc. but without a reason for you needing a file it would be hard to find out how to help. Other maven plugins hate system dependencies, in example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

[Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.4.1. Dependency Scope](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html)

***system***

*[...] you have to provide an explicit path to the JAR on the local file system. [...] The artifact is assumed to always be available and is not looked up in a repository.*

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can take. The most portable would be to specify an additional Maven repo in your project at a path inside (or relative to) `${project.basedir}`. In there, you could install the artifacts you need, in the normal Maven fashion. This way, the build would be portable across environments without modifications.

But, I must say, I only half-understood the question as you never really explain *what* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Someone was unforgiving. Upvoted to cancel it out. :-)